# React Native How to get multiple APIs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, get, fetch

For my project, I have to get several APIs in my projects, these APIs are linked to the others, i.e. they have the same data ...

Here is my code

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
      getData(),
      getData('?page=2'),
    ])
      .then(([dataSource1, dataSource2]) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          isLoading2: false,
          dataSource1,
          dataSource2,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle errors
      });
  }

  render() {
    const getData = (subpath = '') => fetch(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games${subpath}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => result.results);
    console.log(getData)
        

  }
```

I tried with axios but without success ...

When I remove the comment, it shows me only the second fetch ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean, getting mutiple api's?

Comment: Please mention about how the APIs are linked to one another. The provided example hardly explains anything.

Comment: [link](https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=2) is the continuation of the url [link](https://api.rawg.io/api/games), i.e. the 2 api have the same json structure and the same data names. Otherwise, the API would be too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate `fetch` calls for each API. To wait for both to finish, use `Promise.all`.

```
const getData = (subpath = '') => fetch(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games${subpath}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => result.results);
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
        getData(),
        getData('?page=2'),
    ])
        .then(([dataSource1, dataSource2]) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                isLoading2: false,
                dataSource1,
                dataSource2,
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // handle errors
        });
}
```

Comment: I edited my code at the top, taking your code, it gives me an error message, `getData is not defined`.
This message comes from the `Promise.all` below` componentDidMount () `. Sorry if the question is a bit silly, this is my first use of react native.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to define the `getData` function that I defined in the code in the answer.

Comment: You don't *have* to make a `getData` function - you can write out the separate `fetch` calls - but that'd be very WET. Better to write [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code when possible.

Comment: No, put it somewhere that the `Promise.all` call can see it - somewhere in its outer scope, either in `componentDidMount`, or at the same level as the class definition, or somewhere else outer

Comment: Thanks you! In my render, I call getData in my `console.log()`. Inside, I have two promises: `[[PromiseState]]` and `[[PromiseResult]]`, I want to access the `[[PromiseResult]]` to take the array but I can't ... because of the double arrays?

Comment: Use the code in my answer: `.then(([dataSource1, dataSource2]) => {` then call `setState` with those values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224336/discussion-between-xehanorth-and-certainperformance).